# How can i get the element from xaml to C# through Resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just for an example i have the below code in template.xaml.

```
<Border x:Name="PART_ButtonNormal" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Name="PART_ImageBorder" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Margin="2" Width="16"                                         Source="{Binding Path=SmallIcon, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                <Border Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red"/>
             </Grid>
         </Border>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_Text" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"                          
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                    Margin="2,0,4,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I read this xaml in Wrapper.cs class through Resource dictionary. Then how can i access the Image element from template.xaml in Wrapper.cs.

Could you please any one give me the solution?.

Regards,
David C

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `Image` instance after the template is applied to an actual `Control`?  If you are trying to modify the `ControlTemplate` itself before applying it to a `Control`, I'm not sure it is possible.

However, if you are trying to get the Image from a given `Control` that the template is applied to, you can just walk the visual tree:

```
public Image FindImage(Control parent)
{
    Queue<DependencyObject> items = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    items.Enqueue(parent);

    while (items.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = items.Dequeue() as Visual;
        if (item is Image)
            return item;

        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            items.Enqueue(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i));
    }
}
```